# I wanted to use ISO8583 mediator but I am facing the following error

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-data-services-server

I wanted to create an API that will send a message to the following port using WSO2 integration studio but it is displaying the following error

ERROR {SequenceMediator} - {api:Cardless} Sequence named Value {name ='null', keyValue ='org.wso2.carbon.connector.iso8583.sendMessage'} cannot be found

I have tried to use the following sequence but still it is throwing the above error.

```
<sequence name="sendToISO8583Connector" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"> 
<sequence key="org.wso2.carbon.connector.iso8583.sendMessage"/>

    <call>
        <endpoint>
            <address uri="iso8583://192.178.20.5:9058?header=true&amp;isoMessageBeanId=ISO8583Message&amp;timeout=30000">
                <suspendOnFailure>
                    <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                    <progressionFactor>1</progressionFactor>
                </suspendOnFailure>
                <markForSuspension>
                    <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                </markForSuspension>
            </address>
        </endpoint>
    </call>
</sequence>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you haven't deployed your `Sequnce` with the Carbon App. So make sure it's added to the pom of the `Carbon Application Project`.

Having said that, following is how you can use the `iso8583` connector.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/sendiso" name="SendisoTestAPI" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST">
        <inSequence>
            <log>
                <property name="status" value="Sending_an_ISO8583_Messsage"/>
            </log>
            <iso8583.init>
                <serverHost>localhost</serverHost>
                <serverPort>5010</serverPort>
            </iso8583.init>
            <iso8583.sendMessage/>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <log/>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```